# How to insert multiple rows from String in Laravel ManyToMany relationship?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have three tables: authors, books, author_book. Also I have a form:

```
echo Form::open(array('url' => 'add'));


        echo Form::label('name', 'Book name');
        echo Form::text('name','', array('class' => 'form-control'));
        echo '<br/>';


        echo Form::label('author', 'Book author(s) (Separate different authors with commas: Gogebashvili,Turmanidze,Amirejibi)');
        echo Form::text('author','', array('class' => 'form-control'));
        echo '<br/>';

        echo Form::label('year', 'Book year');
        echo Form::text('year','', array('class' => 'form-control'));
        echo '<br/>';

        echo Form::label('title', 'Is book available?:');
        echo Form::checkbox('available', 'value');
        echo '<br/>';

        echo '<br/>';
        echo Form::submit('Click Me!');
        echo Form::close();
```

This form is made for inserting new books with name, author and year in database. The book can have multiple authors so I want to check if author input has string separated with commas, if it does then make it into array and insert one by one in database. Of course it is required to insert in books (Book name, book year, availability), in authors (author name(s)) and in pivot table (author_book). I have all models and Controllers because my code works on just 1 author. Please help to get something creative to solve this problem.

Add book form

```
<?php
        echo Form::open(array('url' => 'add'));


        echo Form::label('name', 'Book name');
        echo Form::text('name','', array('class' => 'form-control'));
        echo '<br/>';


        echo Form::label('author', 'Book author(s) (Separate different authors with commas: Gogebashvili,Turmanidze,Amirejibi)');
        echo Form::text('author','', array('class' => 'form-control'));
        echo '<br/>';

        echo Form::label('year', 'Book year');
        echo Form::text('year','', array('class' => 'form-control'));
        echo '<br/>';

        echo Form::label('title', 'Is book available?:');
        echo Form::checkbox('available', 'value');
        echo '<br/>';

        echo '<br/>';
        echo Form::submit('Click Me!');
        echo Form::close();
?>
```

Author model:

```
class Author extends Model
{
    use HasFactory; 
    public $timestamps = false;

    public function books(){
        return $this->belongsToMany(Book::class);
    }

 }
```

Book model:

```
class Author extends Model
{
    use HasFactory; 
    public $timestamps = false;

    public function books(){
        return $this->belongsToMany(Book::class);
    }

}
```

I need to create BookController and I need your help there.

Comment: Can you show the code where you add the book with one author?

Comment: yeah this shows us nothing of your relations

Comment: Edited. Can you see it please?